# Pointers in C program

Tags: c, pointers

Consider the following 2 codes in C:-
1st code:-

```
int main()
{
    int *a,*b;
    *a=1;
}
```

2nd code:-

```
int main()
{
    int *a,*b;
    *a=1;
    *b=1;
}
```

Both of them compiles without error. But the first one runs and the 2nd one doesn't. Can anyone please explain it?

Comment: Tons of questions like this, you're misunderstanding the concept of pointers.

Comment: What do you know about pointers??? This is utter nonense...

Comment: So, you are saying first one runs just fine????

Comment: Funky undefined behaviour. Does different things in different environments.

Comment: The first one runs just fine. Even I can use something like printf("%d",*a) later. Even though I thought it shouldn't work, it actually works.

Comment: *Even though I thought it shouldn't work, it actually works*  That is called **undefined behaviour**.. It is not guaranteed to work in all platforms, or even in your current platform consistently.

Answer (score 7):

Both of them exhibit undefined behavior: the reason the first one runs is that the pointer that happens to be in `a` by default points to a region in memory writing to which does not happen to cause a crash (it is still illegal). You need to initialize your pointers to fix this problem:

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
int *b = malloc(sizeof(int));
*a = 1;
*b = 1;
free(a);
free(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reson of that problem is that the pointers do not have any memory address, so you must give a legal memory adress before you use them. By the way, both of your codes are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int *a,*b;
    *a=1;
```

Here, `a` and `b` have garbage values (pointing to random locations). When you do, `*a = 1`, it will write(overwrite) to that location wherever it points [provided you are allowed to access it]. At times, this may not work and you will get a `segmentation fault`